# Camera object askew (does not match pose specified by its global transformation matrix)

Tags: python, transforms, camera, constraints

I ran into a (to me) really strange problem. I have a camera that is located at the origin. With various constraints I animate the camera's path to be that of a kite flying an 8 shape pattern (so it does not stay at the origin, it just seems like that in the Transform panel because effects of constraints aren't taken into account quite then). I grab the camera's pose with python via

```
bpy.data.objects['Camera'].matrix_world
```

The translation vector seems to be correct. However, when I place a second camera at the origin and move it to the location and rotation specified by the original camera's transformation matrix, the two camera poses don't quite match up as I had expected (see below, original camera selected/highlighted).

[image: camera and skewed camera]

I figured maybe it just looks like one is askew since I couldn't see a difference in a picture taken with each camera. So I ran some tests with OpenCV trying to project some image points using the same known blender camera pose with each camera. As it turns out though, the cameras really are different. With the original, seemingly askew, camera the projection is off. What's going on here? Did I transform/deform my original camera on accident somehow (didn't even know that was possible...)?

Here's a minimal blend file, only including the necessary constraints and objects for the movement. In frame 1 I added the second camera based on the original camera's transformation matrix. I had a random noise enabled on the location and rotation of the animated camera but it's disabled in the example. I disabled it earlier thinking that that might have caused my problem. The Blender version is 2.73.

[image]

Comment: I think it might be caused Follow curve option of the Follow Path constraint, but is it desired behavior?

Comment: @nilsoe if you bake the animation does the original camera transformation change? you might be copying a weird value due to what you said, but not sure how to explain the behavior